# Python check if list in list of lists with numpy arrays

Tags: python, list, numpy

I want to check if my `query` which is of type `list` is in the `database` (a `list` of `lists`). In the example below it is.

```
query = [np.array([[4,3],[6,4]]),5,2,1,5]

database = [ [np.array([[8,5],[2,1]]),5,3,1,9],
             [np.array([[4,3],[6,4]]),5,2,1,5],
             [np.array([[7,2],[6,4]]),0,0,8,5]]
```

I have tried this:

```
np.any([(query==data) for data in database])
```

However, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. 
Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `np.array_equal` can accept arrays or scalars, you could use it this way:

```
In [107]: any(all(np.array_equal(datum, q) for datum, q in zip(data, query)) for data in database)
Out[107]: True
```

If your scalars are floats, you may wish to use `np.allclose` instead of `np.array_equal` since testing for exact float equality is often not desireable:

```
In [108]: np.array_equal(0.1+0.2, 0.3)
Out[108]: False

In [109]: np.allclose(0.1+0.2, 0.3)
Out[109]: True
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
query = [i.tolist() if isinstance(i, np.ndarray) else i for i in query]
print(np.any([[i.tolist() if isinstance(i, np.ndarray) else i for i in data] == query for data in database]))
```

Output:

```
True
```

Comment: This definitely works thanks. I'm wondering whether there's a simpler (less verbose) solution.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick one-liner

```
np.in1d(["a","b"],["c","k","b"])
```

Returns

```
array([False,  True])
```

It checks if each value of the first list is in the second list and returns True or False for each.

Hope that helps.